# How do execute multiple updates to separate tables and rollback everything if any one of them fails in Teradata

Tags: teradata, rollback

In my .Net webapp, I need to update two tables. I want to commit the updates only if both updates succeed. I'm new to teradata, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Using transactions? In best case put everything into a MultiStatement Request: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1141_151K/ch04.067.11.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Begin Transaction and End Transactions. Put the updates inside the BT ET block as shown below. If any one of the update fails, your transaction will rollback.
For Eg :

```
BT;

updt1;

updt2;

ET;
```